# Find k in $(1-2k)x^2 - (3k+4)x + 2 = 0$ given facts about the roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, quadratic-forms

The exact instruction in my book is:

> 46. A quadratic equation $(1-2k)x^2 - (3k+4)x + 2 = 0$ is given. Find the
>       value of k for each of the following conditions.

(I got 46a and 46b)

> (c) A root of the equation is the negative value of the other root.
>
> (d) A root of the equation is the reciprocal of the other root.

What I tried:

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the roots of the equation.

(c)

$(1-2k)x_1^2 - (3k+4)x_1 + 2 = 0$

$(1-2k)x_2^2 - (3k+4)x_2 + 2 = 0$

$\to (1-2k)x_1^2 - (3k+4)x_1 + 2 = (1-2k)x_2^2 - (3k+4)x_2 + 2$

$\to (1-2k)x_1^2 - (3k+4)x_1 + 2 = (1-2k)x_1^2 + (3k+4)x_1 + 2$

$\to - (3k+4)x_1 = (3k+4)x_1$

$\to x_1 = 0$ or $k = -4/3$

$(x_1 = 0 \to 2 = 0) \to k = -4/3$

Is that right?

(d) The answer given is $k = -1/2$. Wolfram seems to disagree. [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-2k%29%28x%20%2B%201%2Fx%29%20-%20%283k%2B4%29%20%3D%200) [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-2k%29x%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29x%20%2B%202%20%3D%200%2C%20x%3D1%2Fy%2C%20%281-2k%29y%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29y%20%2B%202%20%3D%200)

$(1-2k)x_1^2 - (3k+4)x_1 + 2 = 0$

$(1-2k)x_2^2 - (3k+4)x_2 + 2 = 0$

$\to (1-2k)x_1^2 - (3k+4)x_1 + 2 = (1-2k)x_2^2 - (3k+4)x_2 + 2$

$\to (1-2k)x_1^2 - (3k+4)x_1 = (1-2k)x_2^2 - (3k+4)x_2$

$\to (1-2k)x_1^2 - (3k+4)x_1 = (1-2k)(1/x_1)^2 - (3k+4)(1/x_1)$

$\to (1-2k)[x_1^2 - (1/x_1)^2] - (3k+4)[x_1 - (1/x_1)] = 0$

$\to (1-2k)[x_1 - (1/x_1)][x_1 + (1/x_1)] - (3k+4)[x_1 - (1/x_1)] = 0$

$\to (1-2k)[x_1 + (1/x_1)] - (3k+4) = 0$ or $[x_1 - (1/x_1)] = 0$

$\to (1-2k)[x_1 + (1/x_1)] - (3k+4) = 0$, $x_1 = 1$ or $x_1 = -1$

Case 2: $x_1 = 1$

$\to k = -1/5$

Case 3: $x_1 = -1$

$\to k = -7$

Case 1: $(1-2k)[x_1 + (1/x_1)] - (3k+4) = 0$

Case 1a: $x_1 = 1$

$\to k = -2/7$ or $k = 1/2$

Neither k works with $x_1 = 1$

Case 1b: $x_1 = -1$

$\to k = 6$ or $k = 1/2$

Neither k works with $x_1 = -1$

Case 1c: $x_1 \ne -1$, $x_1 \ne 1$

$\{(x_1, k)| x_1 = {\frac{3k + 4 \pm \sqrt{-7k^2 + 40k + 12}}{2-4k}} \}$

Help please? I think I am supposed to somehow prove $x_1 = 1$ or -1 is false and then show $x_1 = \frac{5-i\sqrt{39}}{8}$ or $x_1 = \frac{5+i\sqrt{39}}{8}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very good logic! I think you are familiar with the following: If $ax^2+bx+c=0$($a\ne0$)is a quadratic equation and its roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$,then
$\alpha+\beta=-b/a$ 
$\alpha \beta=c/a$
Using these,you can easily solve your problem.
Coming to where you probably got stuck:How to refute $x_1=1$ or $-1$?

Dividing given equation by $(1-2k)\ne0$ yields $x^2 - [(3k+4)/(1-2k)]x + 2/(1-2k) = 0$ $\implies$ LHS is a perfect square[both roots are reciprocal so if one root is $1$ other is also $1$]
$x^2 - [(3k+4)/(1-2k)]x + 2/(1-2k) = (x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$ 
Comparing coefficients of $x$ on both sides.You get different values of$k$  $\implies$
$x\ne1$

Same process as above can be applied to show:$x\ne-1$

Comment: Thanks. On the first pargraph: I already edited. Cases 1a and 1b are ruled out. Are cases 2 and 3 ruled out? On the second paragraph: Are we allowed to compare coefficients? I know you can do that in partial fraction decomposition, but can that be done here?  I would say x = 1 in $x^2−[(3k+4)/(1−2k)]x+2/(1−2k)=(x−1)2=x^2−2x+1$ and then solve for k to get, as [Wolfram says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-2k%29x%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29x%20%2B%202%20%3D%200%2C%20x%3D1%2Fy%2C%20%281-2k%29y%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29y%20%2B%202%20%3D%200), $k = -1/5$.

Comment: @BCLC,Of course, we can compare coefficients in$ x^2 - [(3k+4)/(1-2k)]x + 2/(1-2k) = (x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$,because this is an identity.So method of indeterminate coefficient can be applied.

Comment: @BCLC,case 2 and 3 are ruled out because in those cases roots are not reciprocal! $k=-1/2$ and not $-1/5$

Comment: Kilimanjaro, 1 is it really an identity? It holds true for x = 1. What about other x's? Meanwhile $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{1/2}{x-1} + \frac{-1/2}{x+1}$ holds$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ where each expression is defined. 2 case 2 says $x_1 = x_2 = 1$. So, $x_1 = 1/x_2$. case 3 says $x_1 = x_2 = -1$. So, $x_1 = 1/x_2$.

Comment: Look at [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Basic_principles): The equations needs to hold over a field. That equation holds over x = 1.

Comment: @BCLC,suppose you have :$x^2+bx+c=0$ and let this equation have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as roots then $x^2+bx+c=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ for all $x$(Isn't it?)

Comment: Kilimanjaro, yes (it isn't), I think. $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0=x^2+bx+c$ (or $=ax^2+bx+c$?) holds for $x = \alpha$ or $x = \beta$

Comment: No,you are wrong :$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=0=x^2+bx+c$ holds for only $x=\alpha or \beta$ but $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=x^2+bx+c$ holds for all $x$.For example ,you consider $x^2+6x+8=(x+4)(x+2)$,Isn't it true for all $x$.Of course,it is!

Comment: Kilimanjaro, I think [you're right](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438398/when-are-we-allowed-to-match-coefficients?noredirect=1#comment2930243_1438398). Still thinking it over.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thanks again ^-^

Answer (score 2):

If [the roots are distinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), then we can use Vieta's formulas.

(c) One root of the equation is negative of the other. So, sum of the roots is zero. So,$$\frac{3k+4}{1-2k}=0\\ \implies3k+4=0\\ \implies k=-\frac{4}{3}.$$

(d) One root is reciprocal of the other.So, product of the roots is 1. So,
$$\frac{2}{1-2k}=1\\ \implies 2=1-2k\\ \implies k=-\frac{1}{2}.$$

The roots are indeed distinct as assuming repeated roots implies contradictions.

Comment: Just so it's clear, this answer uses the facts that for a quadratic polynomial in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the sum of the roots = $-b/a$ and the product of the roots = $c/a$.

Comment: user223741 and @NoseKnowsAll, thanks, but does that assume two distinct roots? Why can't $x_1 = 1$ ? Why can't $x_1 = -1$ ? [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-2k%29x%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29x%20%2B%202%20%3D%200%2C%20x%3D1%2Fy%2C%20%281-2k%29y%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29y%20%2B%202%20%3D%200) says k can be  -7 or -1/5

Comment: $x_1$ cannot be either 1 or -1 because if you solve for $k$ with that $x_1$, you'll find that your original quadratic after plugging in the corresponding $k$ and 1 or -1 is not equal to 0.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Sorry for the confusion and thanks. That applies for case 1a and 1b. [Does that apply also for cases 2 and 3?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-2k%29x%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29x%20%2B%202%20%3D%200%2C%20x%3D1%2Fy%2C%20%281-2k%29y%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29y%20%2B%202%20%3D%200)

Comment: Yes. In both of those cases, $k=-4/3$ (your wolfram alpha link is not the same cases). Following your final step plugging in $x=1$ or $x=-1$, we have $0-(3k+4) = 0 \implies k=-4/3$. This also yields the same contradiction.

Comment: Btw, @NoseKnowsAll and user223741, Vieta's formulas assume [distinct roots](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html).

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll, if you plug in x = 1 into the original equation, you get k = -1/5. If you plug in x = -1, you get -7. Am I wrong? Where did you get k = -4/3?

Comment: @BCLC $(1-2k)(x_1-1/x_1)-(3k+4)=0$ is another constraint you've reached. Either plugging here $k=-1/5$ or solving for $k$ and plugging both into your original equation, you'll reach a contradiction.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll plus not minus. $x + 1/x_1$