# When are we allowed to match coefficients?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, quadratic-forms, partial-fractions

Related to this answer: [Find k in $(1−2k)x^2−(3k+4)x+2=0$ given facts about the roots.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1438339/140308)

In the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x+1}$, we have:

$0x + 1 = A(x+1) + B(x-1) \to A+B = 0$, $A - B = 1$, where we have matched coefficients.

On the other hand, suppose I was given a quadratic equation

$$(1−2k)x^2−(3k+4)x+2=0$$

and said that its two roots are

$$x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1$$.

It is clear that $k = -1/5$.

However, if $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1$, it is correct to say that $x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0$.

Since $(1−2k)x^2−(3k+4)x+2=0$ is quadratic, $(1−2k)\ne0$.

$\to x^2−\frac{(3k+4)}{(1−2k)}x+\frac{2}{(1−2k)}=0$

$\to x^2 - 2x + 1 = 0 = x^2−\frac{(3k+4)}{(1−2k)}x+\frac{2}{(1−2k)}$

$\to x^2 - 2x + 1 = x^2−\frac{(3k+4)}{(1−2k)}x+\frac{2}{(1−2k)}$

$\to - 2x + 1 =  −\frac{(3k+4)}{(1−2k)}x+\frac{2}{(1−2k)}$

Assuming we can compare coefficients, we have

$- 2 = −\frac{(3k+4)}{(1−2k)}$

$1 = \frac{2}{(1−2k)}$

giving two values of k.

On the other hand, I am doubtful we can compare coefficients because this time we know x = 1. Plugging in x = 1 into:

$- 2x + 1 =  −\frac{(3k+4)}{(1−2k)}x+\frac{2}{(1−2k)}$, we get a unique value of k.

It seems we are allowed to compare coefficients in the partial fraction decomposition problem but not in the quadratic equation problem. Is that right? Why/Why not?

Comment: If $k=-\frac 15$, then $(1-2k)x^2-(3k+4)x+2=0$ becomes $\frac 15(x-1)(7x-10)=0$.

Comment: @mathlove Thanks, but what is the relevance of stating the converse of one of my statements? Edited question for context. I think I was unclear. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what you are asking. Do you understand that $(1-2k)x^2-(3k+4)x+2=0$ cannot have a double root at $x=1$ no matter what $k$ is?

Comment: @mathlove Yes, but if the equation has a double root at $x = 1$, $k = -1/5$.

Comment: No.  "If the equation has **a double root** at $x=1$, then $k=-1/5$" is not true. There is no such $k$. It is true that "If the equation has **a root** at $x=1$, then $k=-1/5$".

Comment: @mathlove Oh, I see! So we *are* allowed to compare coefficients (i.e. [Kilimanjaro is right](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438270/find-k-in-1-2kx2-3k4x-2-0-given-facts-about-the-roots/1438339#1438339)) ?

Comment: @mathlove What precisely is the difference with my question and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-2k%29x%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29x%20%2B%202%20%3D%200%2C%20x%3D1%2Fy%2C%20%281-2k%29y%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29y%20%2B%202%20%3D%200)? Is it that the above question can be rewritten into the one in the Wolfram Alpha link but not vice-versa or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the problem has to do with comparing coefficients. The problem is that you "say" that the roots are $x_1=x_2=1$. You can't say that because you only have one parameter $k$ and you can't use it to fix both roots. As mathlove points out in a comment, upon substituting $k=-1/5$, the resulting equation doesn't in fact have a double root at $x=1$. Thus none of the conclusions that you draw from this fiat are valid.

Comment: Thanks joriki, but I think I was unclear. Sorry for the confusion. Edited question for context. I gave an answer. How do you find it?

Comment: @BCLC: I don't see how the question you linked to in your edit affects any of what I wrote. I'm basically saying the same thing as mathlove is saying in comments, and it appears from your responses that so far you haven't understood those comments. About your answer: I already stated in my answer that I don't think that the problem lies in comparing coefficients.

Comment: joriki, what about [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-2k%29x%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29x%20%2B%202%20%3D%200%2C%20x%3D1%2Fy%2C%20%281-2k%29y%5E2%20-%283k%2B4%29y%20%2B%202%20%3D%200) ? I have a feeling the systems aren't equivalent.

Comment: @BCLC: I strongly disapprove of this style of pitching new questions instead of replying to the arguments presented in response to previous questions. I'm not going to reply to further questions from you before you engage with the arguments I've offered.

Comment: joriki Okaayyy um, what exactly do you mean by 'You can't say that because you only have one parameter k and you can't use it to fix both roots.' ? Does that mean if we assume the equation has a double root at $x = 1$, we would reach a contradiction (namely the one I pointed out in the OP)
?

Comment: @BCLC: The one you pointed out in the OP seems unnecessarily complicated. mathlove showed that a much more immediate contradiction is reached: Substituting the value $k=-1/5$ yields an equation without a double root. Since you correctly deduced $k=-1/5$ from $x=1$, this shows that assuming a double root at $x=1$ leads to a contradiction. This isn't surprising, since there are two roots and only one parameter ($k$). You can fix one root and deduce $k$, and then you have no free parameter left to fix the second root.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. If we assume $x_1 = x_2 = 1$, we get $k = -1/5$ which in turn implies $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 10/7$. Thus we have a contradiction, namely that $1 = 10/7$ hence our initial assumption that $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ is wrong?

Comment: @BCLC: Exactly.

Comment: Thanks joriki. Now if you please, what precisely is the difference between my question and the Wolfram Alpha link? WA did not rule out $x_1 = x_2 = 1$. So I'm guessing my question in OP and what I gave WA are different.

Comment: @BCLC: I don't see much similarity; they're two quite different systems of equations. Perhaps the most important difference is that there are no double roots in what you entered in Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. Thanks joiriki.